# Multiprocessing list search

Tags: python, search, multiprocessing, shared-memory, python-multiprocessing

So I'm using processes and a queue to search through data and find the rows that have the same entry in a different columns. I decided to use multiprocessing to try and make it so can be scaled for large data. The file has a 1000 lines and 10 points of data per line. I read in only 80 lines of the data and the program stalls. 70 lines and it works fine and at a decent speed too.

My question is what am I doing wrong or are the limitations with this approach that I haven't identified? The code isn't perfect by any means and is probably bad in itself. The code is as follows:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import random

def openFile(file_name, k, division):
    i = 0
    dataSet = []
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            stripLine = line.strip('\n')
            splitLine = stripLine.split(division)
            dataSet += [splitLine]
            i += 1
            if(i == k):
                break

    return(dataSet)

def setCombination(q,data1,data2):
    newData = []
    for i in range(0,len(data1)):
        for j in range(0, len(data2)):
            if(data1[i][1] == data2[j][3]):
                newData += data2[j]
    q.put(newData)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Takes in the file, the length of the data to read in, and how the data is divided.
    data = openFile('testing.txt', 80, ' ')
    for i in range(len(data)):
        for j in range(len(data[i])):
            try:
                data[i][j] = float(data[i][j])
            except ValueError:
                 pass

    #print(data)
    k = len(data)//10
    q = Queue()
    processes = [Process(target=setCombination, args=(q, data[k*x: k + k*x], data))
                                                                for x in range(10)]
    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    # Exit the completed processes
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    saleSet = [q.get() for p in processes]
    print('\n', saleSet)
```

The data file [testing.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y6u8vrdc89z4pb6/testing.txt?dl=0)

Comment: 10k data points seems like too few to benefit from multiprocessing. Try writing the simplest single-process, single-thread solution you can first, and then think about parallelizing the solution using higher level constructs such as `multiprocessing.Pool'.

Comment: when using the `with open` construct, you don't need to explicitly close the file. That's the benefit of the with statement

Comment: Do you literally mean the program freezes indefinitely with 80 lines of data, but not 70?

Comment: It looks like the amount of data in `Process(... args=...)` may play a role: with 70 lines, `data` is small enough to fit (where?), with 80, it is not. I'd either load the file anew in each subprocess, or passed the `data` whole, and passed the start / end indices along with it.

Comment: @martineau It is that the program freezes indefinitley.

Comment: @Apalala The reason for 10k is just for testing and getting to run how I expect. The data set I plan to use over 500k rows and about 43 columns. In the final solution two different data sets of similar size will be passed in.

Comment: @9000 I have tried it the way you suggested and the problem persists. I feel opening the file anew may end up slowing the program for larger files

Comment: @Eric: I'd try to add a lot of debug print statements to pinpoint exactly the statement where the program stalls. It's hard to solve a problem without knowing where it happens. Do your subtasks actually start? If they do, where do they stall? Do they all stall at the same point? What happens if you pass an empty list instead of the `data` slice to your tasks, while still using 80 lines everywhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that something about what your code does is causing a deadlock. While experimenting, I noticed that 3 out of the 10 tasks would never terminate,  but, to be honest, I don't really don't know the reason(s) why.

The good news is it's easy to fix by just removing or disabling the

```
# Exit the completed processes
for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

loop you have in your code.

Here's a complete version of your code with (mostly) just that modification in it:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def openFile(file_name, k, division):
    i = 0
    dataSet = []
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            stripLine = line.strip('\n')
            splitLine = stripLine.split(division)
            dataSet += [splitLine]
            i += 1
            if i == k:
                break

    return dataSet

def setCombination(q, data1, data2):
    newData = []
    for i in range(len(data1)):
        for j in range(len(data2)):
            if data1[i][1] == data2[j][3]:
                newData += data2[j]
    q.put(newData)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Takes in the file, the length of the data to read in, and how the data is divided.
    data = openFile('testing.txt', 80, ' ')

    for i in range(len(data)):
        for j in range(len(data[i])):
            try:
                data[i][j] = float(data[i][j])
            except ValueError:
                 pass

    k = len(data) // 10
    q = Queue()
    processes = [Process(target=setCombination, args=(q, data[k*x: k*x+k], data))
                    for x in range(10)]
    for p in processes:
        p.start()

# NO LONGER USED (HANGS)
#    # Exit the completed processes
#    for p in processes:
#        p.join()

    # note: this works since by default, get() will block until it can retrieve something
    saleSet = [q.get() for _ in processes]  # a queue item should be added by each Process
    print('\n', saleSet)
```

Comment: Can you explain how you were able to identify how you found that 3 out of the 10 tasks would never terminate? And is there a way to start all the tasks at once rather than a for loop, but achieve the same result. Would know what I would need to alter if I was comparing strings?

Comment: I identified them by replacing the `for p in processes:`, `p.join()` loop in your code with one that printed a string of `0`s and `1`s indicating which of the 10 processes were `p.is_alive()` over and over until the results were all zeroes. This would quickly became `0000000111` but the last three tasks would never terminate so the loop never ended. I know of no way to start them all at once. but don't think that would change anything. The `setCombination()` function will compare whatever type(s) of data are in the `data1` and `data2` lists passed to it as arguments.

Comment: Afterthought: See my latest revision which makes it work without switching to using a `JoinableQueue`.

Comment: Does this increase efficiency? Or does it make the code easier to read? Or both? I do have another question for you though about python in general. Can I pass the data by reference to the processes so I don't get memory errors on much larger data?

Comment: Don't know if it's more efficient and I suppose code readability is about the same. My original answer using `JoinableQueue` was a bit of a hack, since the latter is really designed to be used with queue _consumer_ threads, not producer threads. You can't pass anything by reference since each task operates in its own memory space with a separate Python interpreter. Multiprocessing `Queue`s are implemented with pipes, so you should be able to handle large amounts of data. Continued...

Comment: ... However if you run into performance problems, there are other ways to share data (that might be more efficient) using a `multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager ` which creates a server process that coordinates the sharing of specific kinds of data (like `list`s and `dict`s) among processes.